# Dynamic forces in Simulink

Tags: friction, simulink, forces

I have the equation of motion:

$a = \frac{1}{m} \left( F_1 - F_2 -F_{fric} \right)$

where a is the acceleration and m is the mass of an object. $F_{fric}$ is the friction calculated as:
$F_{fric} = B \cdot v + F_{coulomb} \cdot sign(v)$

Where v is velocity and B is viscous friction coefficient.

I have a problem when implementing this in Simulink due to the coulomb friction as this increases the simulation time significantly and causes oscillations.

If I don't include the Coulomb term in the dynamic the position goes straight to the upper limit.

Can someone help me come across this problem?

To illustrate a picture of the Simulink structure and the scope of the forces:

[image]

[image]

Zoomed

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the formula $F_{coulomb} \cdot sign(v)$. This [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Dry_friction) page doesn't seem to have this formula. As hinted by the existing answer, you need a better friction model. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_dynamics).

Comment: This is the stribeck friktion model without the stribeck effect https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2012/432129/fig4/

Comment: The attached paper clearly mentions below figure number 4, that, the signum function is used only for **non zero** values of velocity. They give a separate method to calculate friction force for the case where velocity is zero. Your implementation **doesn't** use this additional formula.

Comment: Well, I only have the values for the dry friction and the viscous friction

Answer (score 2):

The sign function gives zero friction force for zero velocity, which is generally not correct (and leads to the artificial oscillations, as the integrator is made for smooth systems and cannot handle discontinuities), since for sticking the friction force is a constraint (absolute value between zero and maximum given by static friction), unless it exceeds the maximal value (static friction). Either you implement a boolean logic checking for transitions from sticking to slipping and vice versa (possibly available in SimMechanics?), or you use a continuous (and thus less accurate) regularization, e.g. an arctan- instead of a sign-function.
Using MatLab instead of SimuLink you may apply event-detection, which is explained by the bouncing ball in the documentation (instead of collisions you would then have to check for stick-slip transitions).

Comment: I am not sure I follow here ? how would you make this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it (time stepping, an alternative to event-detection algorithms) can be done in Python (I am afraid having neither SimuLink nor MatLab at hand, but the algorithm should become clear)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q0 = 0   # initial position
p0 = 0  # initial momentum
t_start = 0   # initial time
t_end = 10   # end time
N = 500 # time points
m = 1   # mass
k = 1   # spring stiffness

muN = 0.5   # friction force (slip and maximal stick)
omega = 1.5   # forcing radian frequency [RAD]
Fstat = 0.1   # static component of external force
Fdyn = 0.6   # amplitude of harmonic external force
F = lambda tt,qq,pp: Fstat + Fdyn*np.sin(omega*tt) - k*qq - muN*np.sign(pp)  # total force, note sign(0)=0 used to disable friction
zero_to_disable_friction = 0

omega0 = np.sqrt(k/m)
print("eigenfrequency   f = {} Hz;   eigen period   T = {} s".format(omega0/(2*np.pi), 2*np.pi/omega0))
print("forcing frequency   f = {} Hz;   forcing period   T = {} s".format(omega/(2*np.pi), 2*np.pi/omega))

time = np.linspace(t_start, t_end, N)   # time grid
h = time[1] - time[0]   # time step
q = np.zeros(N+1)   # position
p = np.zeros(N+1)   # momentum
absFfriction = np.zeros(N+1)

q[0] = q0   
p[0] = p0
for n, tn in enumerate(time):
   
    p1slide = p[n] + h*F(tn, q[n], p[n])   # end-time momentum, assuming sliding
    q1slide = q[n] + h*p1slide/m   # end-time position, assuming sliding
    
    if p[n]*p1slide > 0:   # sliding goes on
        q[n+1] = q1slide
        p[n+1] = p1slide
        absFfriction[n] = muN
        
    else:
        q1stick = q[n]   # assume p1 = 0 at t=tn+h
        Fstick = -p[n]/h - F(tn, q1stick, zero_to_disable_friction)    # friction force needed to stop at t=tn+h
        if np.abs(Fstick) <= muN:
            p[n+1] = 0   # sticking
            q[n+1] = q1stick
            absFfriction[n] = np.abs(Fstick)
        else:  # sliding starts or passes zero crossing of velocity
            q[n+1] = q1slide   # possible refinements (adapt to slip-start or zero crossing)
            p[n+1] = p1slide
            absFfriction[n] = muN
```